# error:Error parsing XML: not well-formed?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, manifest

I keep getting that error message "error:Error parsing XML: not well-formed" when I try to run my code of a virtual device. I don't know what the problem is.

```
 <?xml version="0.03" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.testPro"
     android:versionCode="0.03"
     android:versionName="0.03" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.candybird.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the 0.03 to 1.0 in  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

In [android:versionCode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html),it must be integer

change 0.03 to 1 `android:versionCode="1"`

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.testPro"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="0.03" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.candybird.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This is working but for some reason the orientation lock and the removal of the banner is not working?

Comment: remove this code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and run

Comment: I remove this line but it keeps coming back when I export the project

Comment: ok again remove it and save and do clean the project from Project->clean menu and then Build the project using Build Project option from the same menu, if u ticked Build Automatically option then do the clean process only.